# Facet Search not found in Backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am working on Hybris and see that Facet Search option under System in Backoffice is not present but when I see in HMC I can see the Facet Search under System. Please see the images attached. Let me know why its not visible in Backoffice and how can I add that option to it. Is it a restriction for admin in backoffice or do i need to configure the widget in backoffice. [image: backoffice]

[image: hmc]

Comment: What is your version? I can see in Backoffice version 6.3

Comment: Its version 6.0.0.9, however I was able to see on on Hybris prior version and even the higher version.

Comment: may be it is depending on template/accelerator (b2b, b2c, etc). Which accelerator did you try?

Comment: In your localextensions, have you added `solrfacetsearch` and `solrfacetsearchbackoffice` ?

Comment: I can also see `Facet Search` link just after Personalization in my Hybris 6.3 version. Try Reset Everything in Application Orchestrator by pressing F4 button.

Answer (score 1):

Basically admin user usually has no restriction.

So you should be able to see Facet Search folder just right after Personalization.

Please check that you have added all required solr extensions enabled in you localextensions.xml

- solrfacetsearch
- solrfacetsearchbackoffice
- solrserver

And please execute **ant updatesystem**